# ProcessInstanceWorkitem Wizard StageManager must not be longer than 40 characters

Tags: apex

I am looking for some help here.

The below is code :

```
Public class actcontoller{ 
public Schema.SObjectType objType {get;set;}
public List<processinstanceworkitem> process {get; set;}
public actcontoller() {
Process=[select id, actorid ,ProcessInstanceId, processinstance.targetobjectid,processinstance.targetobject.name ,CreatedDate from processinstanceworkitem where actorid = :userinfo.getuserid() LIMIT 5];
                  for( processinstanceworkitem p:process){
                  objType = P.processinstance.targetobjectid.getSobjectType();
                  //PrcocessID=p.ID;
                  }
}
}
```

Vf Page:

```
                <!--<apex:column headerValue="Type">
                    <apex:outputLink target="_top" value="{!URLFOR($Action.Task.View, task.Id)}">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!task.Id}"/>
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>-->
                <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                <apex:outputLink target="_top" value="p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id={!task.Id}">Approve/Reject</apex:outputLink>

                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Related To" value="{!task.processinstance.targetobjectid}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!objType}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Date Submitted" value="{!task.CreatedDate}"/>                    
                </apex:pageBlockTable>           
            </apex:pageBlock>
```

When i click on approve/reject click i am getting the above error in Title.

Comment: do we have any sample code for Exact replica for Items to Approve section n the HOME page layout using Visualforce Page?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the value of your outputLink tag is too long.  Change the outputLink to a commandLink that returns a PageReference instead.  See the following example for more information: [Link to Approval Process Screen](http://lc169.blogspot.com/2013/07/link-to-approval-process-screen.html)